# Add module to angstrom kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, angstrom-linux

I'm working on the Altera cyclone V Soc FPGA Dev Kit. 
I'm using the GSRD 14.1 Angstrom provides by rocketboards.com (http://www.rocketboards.org/foswiki/Documentation/GSRD141AngstromGettingStarted)

```
root@socfpga_cyclone5:~# uname -a
Linux socfpga_cyclone5 3.10.31-ltsi
```

This kernel don't support usb serial device and I think that I need to add usbserial and maybe usbcore drivers to communicate with a GPS serial module. The kernel includes insmod and modprobe but I can't find specifics driver for my board.

dmesg returns:

```
usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using dwc2
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-1: Product: CP2104 USB to UART Bridge Controller
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 006FA62E
```

Is there a solution to add this module ?
If I have to rebuild and customize the kernel, I'm looking for some advise :)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The solution was add the serial driver support in menuconfig and update the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, plug your serial device into the USB port and check the output of this command :

> ls /dev |grep usb

If you see something like "ttyUSB0" or "ttyAMC0", then the driver is already there, either as a statically compile driver or loaded module. I would be really surprised if your issue really is that the driver isn't present; it should be included in just about every distribution.

If nothing comes up, then check to see if the driver is currently loaded (this will tell you if it's actually a problem with your USB-serial device:

> lsmod | grep serial

(Note: the module should be called "usb_serial", but I usually grep for a subset of the string I'm actually looking for to catch names that don't quite match what I expect, such as names with or without underscores in them. "grep serial" can match more than "usb_serial", but should include it while still shortening the modprobe output.")

If you see the driver there, then driver is loaded and the problem is with your USB-serial device. Check [this text document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usb-serial.txt) to see if your device is supported by the driver. It is possible that your device will still work even if it's not listed as supported, because there is support for a generic device in the usb serial module. You'll have to reload the module with this command to take advantage of it:

> insmod usbserial vendor=0x#### product=0x####

If the driver isn't loaded, use this command to see if it's available:

> modprobe | grep serial

If the driver is there but not currently loaded, you should be able to find it in this directory to use "insmod" on it:

> /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/`

If all of that fails, you may have to recompile with the drivers enabled. Recompile your kernel and make sure you enable USB_SERIAL under the USB menu, and also enable kernel support for TTY, because USB_SERIAL [depends on it](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/serial/Kconfig#L7).

Comment: Thanks, There is no changes in /dev and lsmod usbserial returns "not such file or directory". I will try to recompile the kernel and enable USB_SERIAL like you said